# Emacs: pop-up bottom window for temporary buffers

Tags: emacs, elisp

I would like to have a pop-up bottom window for temporary buffers like *compilation*, *Completions*, etc. It should split-vertically the whole frame even if root window was split horizontally. For example:
Before M-x compile:

```
+------+------+
|      |      |
|      |      |
|      |      |
+------+------+
```

After:

```
+------+------+
|      |      |
+------+------+
|             |
+------+------+
```

I'm absolutely satisfied with [ecb-compilation-window](http://ecb.sourceforge.net/docs/ecb-compilation.html), but I don't want to use ECB and CEDET.
Actually I see two ways make described behavior but both have their drawbacks.

- Use [split-root.el](http://nschum.de/src/emacs/split-root/) module.

**Drawback:** it uses delete-other-windows function and then rebuilds previous windows tree after root window is split as required. It invalidates all references to existed earlier windows in your code(or code of any module).

- Set window-min-height variable to its minimal possible value(1) and call split-window-vertically during emacs startup minimizing window height after it's created. Then use this window for temporary buffers setting its height as required.

**Drawbacks:** Small annoying window with annoying modeline on the bottom of the frame, doesn't work with emacs --daemon.

Are there more elegant ways to do that *without drawbacks*?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Use [popwin](https://github.com/m2ym/popwin-el) !

It behaves as you describe out of the box, and configuration is easy, it only took one line to get my anything buffers to pop-up at the bottom of the screen :

> (push '("\*anything*" :regexp t :height 20) popwin:special-display-config)

There some more detailed config examples floating around japanese blogs, just google it.

Comment: Wait, this works the same way and so has exactly the same drawback as the split-root.el library already mentioned in the question.

Comment: Well, popwin is better than split-root(because it's easy to configure and haven't problems with restoring of original size of vertical windows), but it has the same problems split-root has. Anyway, I like popwin and I think I can bear with its drawbacks. Thanks.